# unknown issue with mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I did

```
 $query ="CREATE TABLE '{$uname}'
    (id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    fname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    lname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    pass varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    subj varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    test1 int(11) NOT NULL,
    test2 int(11) NOT NULL,
    exam int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id))";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    if(!$result2){echo mysql_error();}
```

and the error I get is:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''nelo' (id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, fname varchar(255) NOT NULL, l' at line 1`

when I did a `vardump` of `$query`, I got:

```
string 'CREATE TABLE 'nelo'
(id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
fname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
lname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
pass varchar(255) NOT NULL,
subj varchar(255) NOT NULL,
test1 int(11) NOT NULL,
test2 int(11) NOT NULL,
exam int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id))' (length=277)
```

which seems cool to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: reformat your code , or I may need to see an optician

Comment: remove the quotes from the table name

Comment: Use backticks, not quotes for table and/or column names

Comment: I'm sure I did that @poomrokc

Comment: Just remove single codes from table name  and delete (length=277) at end of your SQL command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write your query like this:

```
 $query ="CREATE TABLE `".$uname."`
    (id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    fname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    lname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    pass varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    subj varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    test1 int(11) NOT NULL,
    test2 int(11) NOT NULL,
    exam int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id))";
```

This will work for you properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query ="CREATE TABLE `$uname` 
    (id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    fname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    lname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    pass varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    subj varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    test1 int(11) NOT NULL,
    test2 int(11) NOT NULL,
    exam int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id))";
```

You are enclosing the table name with '' which was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Either this-

```
CREATE TABLE `nelo`
(id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
fname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
lname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
pass varchar(255) NOT NULL,
subj varchar(255) NOT NULL,
test1 int(11) NOT NULL,
test2 int(11) NOT NULL,
exam int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

or this -

```
CREATE TABLE nelo
(id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
fname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
lname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
pass varchar(255) NOT NULL,
subj varchar(255) NOT NULL,
test1 int(11) NOT NULL,
test2 int(11) NOT NULL,
exam int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 $query ="CREATE TABLE ".$uname."
    (id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    fname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    lname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    pass varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    subj varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    test1 int(11) NOT NULL,
    test2 int(11) NOT NULL,
    exam int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id))";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    if(!$result2){echo mysql_error();}
```